# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '62,6'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, valueerror

I am trying to convert dataframe to numpy array:

```
dataset = myset.values
X = np.array(dataset[0:,6:68], dtype="float32")
X[0:5,0:]
```

[Here is a piece of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/970OB.png)

Here is an error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

----
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-4b67608047d1> in <module>()
      1 dataset = myset.values
----> 2 X = np.array(dataset[0:,6:68], dtype="float32")
      3 X[0:5,0:]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '62,6'
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: `,` is not a valid decimal separator.
You either use `decimal=','` in the dataset loader or replace `','` with `'.'` then parse as float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `,` to `.`:

```
dataset = myset.replace(',','.', regex=True).values
```

Or use parameter `decimal` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert `,` to `.` in floats:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('file', decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are locales that use '.' as decimal separator and ',' as thousands-separator.
There are also locales that use ',' as decimal separator and '.' as thousands-separator.

Doing a plain string-replace will get you in all sorts of trouble. You need to

```
import locale
```

then specify which locale you want to use, e.g.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'german')
```

and then you can parse the string using

```
locale.atof('1.337,3')
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, this should be `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

In Python (or basically any programming language used today), a dot (`.`) is used for decimal point, not a comma (`,`), so you should replace the commas with dots in the string you're dealing with.